# React Virtualized - Render Table with full height to show all rows

Tags: react-virtualized

According to the react-virtualized docs, "The AutoSizer component decorates a React element and automatically manages width and height properties so that decorated element fills the available space".

The suggestion is usually to add `height: 100%;` or `flex: 1;` to all parent elements in the DOM to render the table's full height.

What if one of those elements, e.g. an absolutely positioned full page overlay container, has `height: 100vh; overflow: scroll;` ?

In this case, the Table's parent height is 100vh, but allows overflow if the children have height greater than 100vh.

Say our table has many rows of varying height and exceeds 100vh when rendered. Autosizer will return a height in pixels that equals 100vh, as a maximum, meaning the last rows in our table will be cutoff as AutoSizer will not stretch its parents height to render all rows.

My current workaround is to use `<CellMeasurer />` and `CellMeasurerCache()` to manually determine table height from `this.cache; // (component instance of CellMeasurerCache)` using private properties, for example in my table component:

```
  componentDidUpdate = () => {
    const { tableHeight } = this.state;

    const tableRowHeights = Object.values(this.cache._rowHeightCache);
    const newRowsHeight = tableRowHeights.reduce(
      (height, nextRowHeight) => height + nextRowHeight,
      0
    );

    if (tableHeight !== newRowsHeight) {
      this.setState({ tableHeight: newRowsHeight });
    }
  }
```

Is there no way to accomplish this with react-virtualized components and APIs,without accessing private properties from the `CellMeasurerCache()` instance?

Answer (score 3):

> What if one of those elements, e.g. an absolutely positioned full page overlay container, has height: 100vh; overflow: scroll; ?
>
> In this case, the Table's parent height is 100vh, but allows overflow if the children have height greater than 100vh.

I don't think this (overflow behavior) make sense in the case of react-virtualized. In most cases- unless you're using `WindowScroller` for a Facebook/Twitter like layout- react-virtualized components should manage their own scrolling.

So in that case, if 100vh height is available, you would want RV to fill exactly that amount and- if there's more content than will fit into that area- (which is likely, if you're using RV in the first place)- it will setup the scrolling styles within itself.

On the other hand, if you tell a react-virtualized component that its height is `numRows * rowHeight` then it's going to render everything, and completely defeat the purpose of windowing. :)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer Brian. I checked out the `WindowScroller` example and realized that `<Table />` has an `autoHeight` prop (meant to be used with WindowScroll), which is exactly what I was looking for.  

I agree that my use case is atypical, but I have used react-virtualized for the generic `<Table />` component in my app, so it should support as many use cases as possible.